# Page template for blog not working

Tags: page-template

So I have a general template called home.php for displaying all blog posts. All fine.

No I've wanted to add the same thing with sidebar, so I've copied it, added sidebar, called home-sidebar.php, added the comments... all fine.

I've went to backend, pages, chose the template and nothing. Still the same. It seems like no matter what I do I can not change the template for a page that displays all posts (the blog).

In other pages it works fine. What is going on? And don't send me to hierarchy pages - I've got one printed out right in front of me.

Comment: Do you have your posts page set in settings -> reading? If so I believe it will always use the home.php regardless of what you set on the post itself. Blake

Comment: @Blake Really? I could swear that there is some kind of way to change that with a template.... So I can't have an option of choosing like sirebar/no sidebar blog option?